How to generate multiple packages using sqlc and golang
I am working with sqlc in golang. Most of the work has been very good. But now my project is growing a little bit an I am struggling to have some level of organization
I am organizing my sqls in repository files like:
├── queries
│   ├── objects.sql
│   ├── object_versions.sql
│   └── project_config.sql

I wanted a package to each of the queries, so I come up with the following sqlc.yaml config
version: "2"
sql:
  - &default
    name: "common"
    engine: "postgresql"
    queries: "./internal/db/queries.sql"
    schema: "./internal/db/shared_schema.sql"
    gen:
      go: &go_defaults
        package: "common"
        out: "internal/db/repository/common"
        sql_package: "pgx/v5"
        emit_json_tags: true
  - <<: *default
    name: "objects"
    engine: "postgresql"
    queries: "./internal/db/queries/objects.sql"
    gen:
      go:
        <<: *go_defaults
        package: "objects"
        out: "internal/db/repository/objects"
  - <<: *default
    name: "object_versions"
    engine: "postgresql"
    queries: "./internal/db/queries/object_versions.sql"
    gen:
      go:
        <<: *go_defaults
        package: "objects_version"
        out: "internal/db/repository/objects_version"
  - name: "project_config"
    engine: "postgresql"
    queries: "./internal/db/queries/project_config.sql"
    schema: "./internal/db/shared_schema.sql"
    gen:
      go:
        <<: *go_defaults
        package: "project_config"
        out: "internal/db/repository/project_config"


When I split one .sql for each item the sql array, I am able to generate almost my desired output: Except that the models.go keep being generated for each of them
├── repository
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── copyfrom.go
│   │   ├── db.go
│   │   ├── models.go
│   │   └── queries.sql.go
│   ├── objects
│   │   ├── db.go
│   │   ├── models.go
│   │   └── objects.sql.go
│   ├── objects_version
│   │   ├── db.go
│   │   ├── models.go
│   │   └── object_versions.sql.go
│   └── project_config
│       ├── db.go
│       ├── models.go
│       └── project_config.sql.go
├── seed.sql
└── shared_schema.sql


From the current version of my sqlc.yaml, that is kind of obvious. What isn't obvious though it is how can I have a unique separate models.go file that is shared between my query pckages.
Using all my queries from the same package is not the biggest problem. The biggest issue is that I can't have the same names for queries in different files. Which is very annoying.
Is there any way that I can have a shared models.go across my generated packages?

It would be great to have a single db.go file across packages too

Yeah, I believe the feature I want isn't available. I read the whole documentation and couldn't find it. I wonder if this is on their roadmap.

This issue is probably the one to watch (it's being explored in the roadmap).

You can use "omit_unused_structs" not to have duplicate model definitions. Reference

Nope, it actually does something different: "If true, sqlc won’t generate table and enum structs that aren’t used in queries for a given package. Defaults to false"
